# Forms Messing up my Footer

Tags: html, css, footer

The easiest way is to observe this live

Homepage footer (looks good): www.fishingreports.com

Screwed up footer: www.fishingreports.com/users/register

Whenever I export the code from /users/register onto another page like this: www.fishingreports.com/texas/lake-texoma

you can see the footer also goes haywire. I'm sure I'm missing something here that keeps the rest of the page in line.

Something interesting to note is that when there is OTHER STUFF on the page the footer acts fine, but when the form is the semi-last thing on the page the footer screws up. Compare these two pages:

http://www.fishingreports.com/washington/lake-saint-clair  (good)
http://www.fishingreports.com/washington/lake-leota (bad footer!)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please review: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Already asked 4 questions and still 1 reputation? I feel sorry for having answered your question. When an answer helped you: upvote it. When an answer is the answer your need: accept it (tick the checkmark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the pages where the footer is messed up the footer is a part of the container `div`, causing the padding to apply and the size of the footer to be reduced.

You most probably have an unclosed div issue, this tool can help you with that: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fishingreports.com%2Fusers%2Fregister&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Good luck.